Proof for the partial solutions for a polynomial ideal being included in the ideal itself.
Let $I$ be in ideal of the polynomial ring in $n$ varibales, $\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]=\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $V(I)$ be the algebraic set of $I$, and $v\in V(I)$ an element of the form:
$$v=(z_1,...,z_n);\quad z_i\in\mathbb{F}$$
For every $i$, there is a natural ring homomorphism $\phi_i:\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]\rightarrow \mathbb{F}[\vec{y}_i]$ given by the substitution:
$$\phi_i(p(\vec{x}))=p(x_1,...,z_i,...,x_n)$$
$$p\mapsto p; x_i\mapsto z_i$$
$p\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$. Since $\phi_i$ is a homomorphism, $\phi_i(I)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{F}[\vec{y}_i]$. I want to prove that $\phi_i(I)\subseteq I$.
That this might be the case can be seen by the following argument: for every $p\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$,
$$p=\sum_ka_k\vec{x}^k$$
where $a_k\in\mathbb{F}$, and $\vec{x}^k=x_1^{jk_1}...x_n^{jk_n}$,$jk_l\in\mathbb{N}$, so
$$\phi_i(p)=\sum_ka_kz_i^{jk_i}\frac{\vec{x}^k}{x_i^{jk
_i}}=\sum_kb_k\frac{\vec{x}^k}{x_i^{jk_i}}$$
with $b_k\in\mathbb{F}$, and hence $p\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]\Rightarrow\phi_i(\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}])\subseteq\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$, so $\phi_i$ is an endomorphism. Obviously, $x_i\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$ and $x_i\notin\phi_i(\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}])$, so $\phi_i$ is a surjective endomorphism and a ring homomorphism... But this alone doesn't seem to be enough to prove $\phi_i(I)\subseteq I$. I find it to be a useful fact that $I$ must be contained in another ideal $J$, $I\subseteq J$, of the form:
$$J=\sum_i\langle x_i-z_i\rangle$$
This question is relevant for elimination theory, to find algebraic sets for polynomial ideals of the form:
$$\sum_i\langle f_i\rangle$$
With $f_i\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$.
